# Past Perfect or Past Simple?

Tags: tenses, past-perfect, simple-past

I am writing a text on theatre. I would like to put in one sentence two different time references:

"The model has recently been popular in the academia"

AND

"It was theorized about 50 years ago by X"

The sentence would go along the lines of:

"What has recently been popular in the academia **was/had already been** theorized about 50 years ago by X"

I'm wondering whether I should use the Past Simple form as there are no 2 different past reference points or the Past Perfect form - since 50 years is a long time and I would like to emphasize the fact.

Comment: The example shows two time frames: **1** *{"What has recently been popular in the academia}* = recent past and present. and **2** *{was/had already been theorized about 50 years ago by X}"* = completed in the [distant] past. So as to more clearly separate the two ideas, the older, *completed* action (theorised) is placed in the past perfect. This then creates the gap between past and present. The use of the past perfect is also justified by *"{was/had already been theorized about 50 years ago by X}"* being preparatory to the current comment/event.

Comment: @Greybeard That was my intuition but since the 1st time frame is literally 'present', is Past Simple for the 2nd time frame not enough?

Comment: Either tense is grammatical. You could also use **was** ***already*** or **has already been**. This is purely a matter of style and choice.

Comment: @JasonBassford But I do need to include the "50 years ago" bit, so "has been" seems like a contradiction, doesn't it?

Comment: @JulesCocovin No. All past tenses are still past tenses, and they all correspond to the use of *ago*. Whether *has been* would be completely natural, is something different. But it's definitely syntactically correct. Note, too, that in my comment I used *has **already** been*. That makes a big difference in terms of it being idiomatic.

Comment: @JulesCocovin I ran out of space above. I should have mentioned that the past perfect is commoner in writing and is mainly used to set the background/context for the main subject (theme). The theme is *{"What has recently been popular in the academia}*, the background to which is *{[It] had already been theorized about 50 years ago by X}*. Of course, this is not a rule - rather idiomatic.